# Insert tags within a string

Tags: php, regex

Wondering if anyone can help me out here, is there any relatively simple way of inserting some tags with a given string after a certain amount of words...

for example, taking:

```
$string = 'Helping customers to do something everyday';
```

and inserting a  after every third word so the output would be

```
Helping customers to </span><span> do something everyday
```

I'm guessing the use of a regular expression of some sort, but they are not my strong point or perhaps within a for loop?

/////////////////////////////

UPDATE:

Cheers for the help guys:

I had a brainwave and come up with this function, which done exactly what I needed:

```
function insert_tags ( $string )
{
$string = explode ( " ", $string );

$count = 0;
$result = '';

foreach ( $string as $s )
{   
    if ( $count == 3 )
    {
        $result .= '</span><span>' . $s . ' ';
        $count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $result .= $s . ' ';
    }

    $count++;
}

return $result;
  }
```

Comment: Might as well use a for loop when you do a count. Look at my answer below :) .. Also, you're code will return `Helping customers to </span><span>do something` note the missing space before do. This is fixed with a space after your span tag

Comment: ignore my comment about the missing space -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little like @tandu's response, but I just prefer this method. It won't put a span tag at the end of the line.

```
function insert_tags($string) {
    $exString = explode(' ', $string);
    $newString = array();
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($exString); $i++) {
        if($i % 3 == 0 and $i != 0) {
            $newString[] = '</span><span>';
        }
        $newString[] = $exString[$i];
    }
    $newString = implode(' ', $newString);
    return $newString;
}
```

Test returns:

```
Helping customers to <span></span> do something everyday
Helping customers to <span></span> do something everyday <span></span> okay there a
Helping customers to <span></span> do something everyday <span></span> okay there a <span></span> a
Helping customers to <span></span> do something everyday <span></span> okay there
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a regex:

```
`preg_replace('/\b\w+\b{3}/', '\0 </span><span>' ...`
```

But it may be nicer to do it with an array, assuming words are separated only by single spaces:

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$chunks = array_chunk($words, 3);
$final = '';
foreach ($chunks as $words) {
   $final .= implode(' ', $words) . ' </span><span>';
}
```

Note that both of these can have a final `</span><span>`, so if that's a problem you will have to trim it manually or just improve on what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
((?:\b.+?\b ?){3})
```

Replace with:

```
<span>$1</span>
```

So in your code:

```
$string = 'Helping customers to do something everyday';
$pattern = '/((?:\b.+?\b ?){3})/';
$replacement = '<span>$1</span>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

My regex tester shows this as the result:

```
<span>Helping customers to </span><span>do something everyday</span>
```

I'm not 100% au fait with PHP, so let me know how you go!

Comment: Sorry mate, that didn't do it with the PHP. It just showed the first word!

Comment: Whoops, forgot slashes in the pattern, try now.